# How to link to the same page with a different parameter in SolidJS using SSG

Tags: javascript, anchor, solid-js, static-site-generation

I am struggling to get my SolidJS app to link user pages together using Static Site Generation (SSG).

```
/* App.jsx */
<Routes path="/user">
  <Route path="/:id" component={ User } />
</Routes>

function User() {
  const params = useParams()
  return (
    <OtherUsers url={ "json/photo/" + params.id } />
    /* More Components here */
  )
}

function OtherUsers(props) {
  const [users] = createResource(() => server.fetchData(props.url))
  return (
    <>
      <Show when={ users() }><Show when={ users()[0] }>
        <For each={ users() }>
          {(num, key) => 
          <img src={ num.photo } />
          <a href={ "/user/" + num.id } >{ num.name }</a>
          /* More fetched content here */
          }
        </For>
      </Show></Show>
    </>
  )
}
```

This work as expected in the development environment `npm run dev`. For example, I can navigate from `/user/123` to `/user/456`.
However when constructed as a Static Site Generation (SSG) website `npm run build`, the anchor tag directs the browser to a page that doesn't exist. For example, `/user/456` returns a 404 error when navigating from `/user/123` using the `<a>` tag (using SSG).

I have two solutions to fix the 404 error - but the both cause SolidJS to stop updating the page when the link is clicked.

**First**, the `<A>` component.

```
import { A } from "@solidjs/router"
...
<A href={ "/user/" + num.id } >{ num.name }</A>
```

**Second**, the `useNavigate` component.

```
import { useNavigate } from "@solidjs/router"
const navigate = useNavigate()
...
navigate("/user/" + num.id, { replace: true })
```

Both of these solutions update the url in the browser and the `params.id` appears to update. However `User()` and `OtherUsers()` are not triggered and so nothing on the page is re-drawn.

**How do I force the page to re-draw?**

Answer (score 1):

> However when constructed as a Static Site Generation (SSG) website, the anchor tag directs the browser to a page that doesn't exist

How do you serve your SSG site? You may need to setup redirects.

Is it viable for you to use the Hash router integration?
https://docs.solidjs.com/guides/how-to-guides/routing-in-solid/solid-router#hash-mode-router

Comment: I've just tested `hashIntegration`. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. It adds a hash symbol to the urls. So `/user/123` becomes `/#/user/123` but the problem described in my question remains.

Comment: My SSG site is a full static HTML website. Generated once by running `npm run build`. https://docs.solidjs.com/references/concepts/ssr/ssg

Comment: How are you serving your pages?

Comment: The SSG site is static html files in a really simple node.js server `npm install -g http-server`. Everything works except navigation from an `x/:id` page to a different `x/:id` page.

Comment: If you visit user/123 without Solid Router, but typing it in your browser instead, does that work as well? If the HTML page has been generated, it should be served.
I would generally recommend Astro for a SSG site like that, as it takes care of a lot of the underlying render stuff for you.

Comment: `npm run build` only generates a single index.html file. So typing in user/123 and pressing enter returns a 404 error. I'm using `import { A } from "@solidjs/router"` to navigate users from the index.html root.

Comment: Astro looks cool but I'm sure I don't need it if I can simply get the page to update in this one specific edge case.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/ryansolid/solid-ssr-workbench ? I tried it and it works fine. Maybe your forgot to Hydrate your app, causing the Solid Router to not work, and falling back to browser navigation?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So how do I get my app to hydrate when navigating from `/user/123` to `/user/456`? It successfully hydrates when navigation to/from all other pages.

Comment: Your app hydrates once, when it's mounted. You can test this by using some state and letting Solid update (like an interval on a counter). If the counter updates, your page is hydrated. I feel like in your case SSG is not the right approach though: you have a dynamic URL, you want prerendered pages and SPA-like navigation? Maybe try vite-ssr-plugin with Solid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SolidJS to create an Static Site Generation (SSG) app without setting up a complex server. App navigation must always start at `index.html` because this is the only html file generated when running `npm run build`. Here are some guidelines.

**Anchor Tags**

Avoid using `<a>` anchor tags. They prompt your browser to reload another url causing a 404 page not found error. Instead, use the `<A>` component to to dynamically change the route.

**Resources Signals and Effects**

Avoid using the SolidJS `createResource` component. It does not re-trigger when the properties of it's parent component change.

```
/* Don't do this */
const [images] = createResource(() => server.fetchData(props.url))
```

Instead, use `createEffect` to trigger whenever the properties of the parent component change and `createSignal` for the data of the DOM elements that you want re-drawn.

```
/* Do this */
const [images, setImages] = createSignal([])
createEffect(() => {
  server.fetchData(props.url).then(json => setImages(json))
})
```